# Simple CSS: Text won't center in a button

Tags: css

In Firefox 'A' shows in the middle, on Chrome/IE it doesn't:

```
<button type="button" style="width:24px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">A</button>
```

Note the following has the same results:

```
<button type="button" style="width:24px;">A</button>
```

Edit: Now seems to be fixed in Chrome 5.0

Comment: Seems to be working here: http://jsbin.com/ohecu/. It might not look centered because 24px is rather small.

Comment: I know, unfortunately I need it to be that size. There is still space, it works in Firefox but doesn't in Chrome.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Testing this in Chrome, you need to add

```
padding: 0px;
```

To the CSS.

Comment: IE instills its own padding on buttons (thanks Windows). Button formatting is annoying because it takes on OS and browser specific formatting. It's the same reason you can adjust the size of `<input type="text">` or style buttons in browsers in Safari. You would do well to remember to always use a CSS reset.

Comment: This didn't occur to me. Thank you, worked as expected for Chrome! Although it did unfortunately cause Firefox to now be a little off center.

Comment: Actually if anyone else has this problem here is the fix that works consistent across IE, FF and Chrome:
<pre>padding:0 3px 0 3px; /* Purely for IE, however doesn't affect Firefox. Chrome requires 0 */</pre>
<code>-webkit-padding-start: 0;</code>

Comment: @gbhall - seems like a lot of work to just get some text centered on a button, when if you would use `<input type="button" style="width:24px;" value="A"/>`, it would just work.

Comment: @gmcalab - that actually wont work in Chrome. It's putting padding into the left side of the button, and why this particular CSS fix is required.

Comment: @Tejs - `<input type="button" style="width:24px;" value="A"/>` works in all browsers. He was using `<button type="button" style="width:24px;" value="A"/>` where I am using `<input>`

Comment: @Gabe, I can confirm that that _doesn't_ work in chrome.

Comment: haha, padding doesn't work for me, my button has a bun of html inside and it's flex, so `justify-content` works for me

Answer (score 19):

`padding: 0px` solves the horizontal centering 
whereas,  
setting `line-height` equal to or less than the height of the button solves the vertical alignment.

```js
line-height: 0px;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for this life saver!

Answer (score 4):

Usualy, your code should work...

But here is a way to center text in css:

```
.text
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This has proved to be bulletproof to me whenever I want to center text with css.

Answer (score 2):

As a more brute force method that I found worked for me:

First wrap the text inside the button in a span, and then apply this css to that span

```
var spanStyle = {
      position: "absolute",
      top: "50%",
      left: "50%",
      transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
    }
```

*above setup for inline styling

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that buttons render differently across browsers. In Firefox, 24px is sufficient to cover the default padding and space allowed for your "A" character and center it. In IE and Chrome, it does not, so it defaults to the minimum value needed to cover the left padding and the text without cutting it off, but without adding any additional width to the button.

You can either increase the width, or as suggested above, alter the padding. If you take away the explicit width, it should work too.

Answer (score 0):

make sure:

```
box-sizing : content-box;
```

Comment: this actually was important for me, together with the line-height recommended above

Answer (score 0):

I notice the same issue due to some UI fixies.
Below, I'll demonstrate how I fixed this bug:

.html

```
<button className='registration_button'>
 Registration
</button>
```

.scss

```
  .registration_button {

    //solve the vertical centering
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 1.25rem; 

    //solve the horizontal centering    
    padding: 0px;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
<input type="button" style="width:24px;" value="A"/>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can bootstrap. Now a days, almost all websites are developed using bootstrap. You can simply add bootstrap `link` in `head` of html file. Now simply add `class="btn btn-primary"` and your button will look like a normal button. Even you can use `btn` class on `a` tag as well, it will look like button on UI.

Comment: This is massive overkill for a simply layout issue.